# Using Distinct and Sum in my sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

below is the table i have created, my goal is to remove the duplicate results then add the value up.

```
|  username   |   value
|    Bobby    |     5
|    Bobby    |     5
|    Bobby    |     7
```

This is the result I am looking for

```
|  username   |   value
|    Bobby    |     12
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `SELECT 
      username, SUM(value)
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY username`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select username, sum(value) from 
(select distinct username,value from mytbl) as tmp  group by username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT value) FROM TableName Group By UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
 select username,sum(value) from 
 (
   select username,value from tbl group by username,value
 )data
  group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's simpler way

```
SELECT distinct(username), sum(distinct value) AS Value from temp1
```

**It works for sure**